# How to debug a window service dump file (.dmp) in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-services, dmp

I have been provided with a dump files of a window service application, (let's say `CalendarService.dmp` and `CalendarServicemini.dmp`). Tester has been reporting the issue of high CPU utilization (almost 100%) while window service is running on test server. He has created a dump file of that service and sent it to us. The window service is part of a solution file which consists of other service projects and class libraries.

I have tried opening the solution file at my end and at the same time opened the dump file in the same window, where I was shown with different options under Action. Following are the list of actions selected with the output received followed with the small DLL loading window.

For **Debug with Managed Only** received **Source Not Available**

For **Debug with Mixed** received **Source Not Available**

For **Debug with Native Only** received **The application is in break mode**

This is for the first time, I am using such functionality and I am not sure about the basic requirements and setup needed to reproduce the issue of high CPU utilization. Also it would be good to know if such scenarios can be debug at my end using the dump files. Can somebody please put me in the right direction?

Comment: Creating a minidump makes a snapshot with the program in an arbitrary state.  Always good odds that it happens while it is busy in a OS call, you won't have source to look at.  Also the basic reason why a minidump is often useless to diagnose perf programs, use a profiler.  Be sure to pick the correct thread with Debug > Windows > Threads.  And look at the Call Stack window to find your code back.  And consider to limit the number of threads you use so you can't completely hog the processor.  And consider that he sees 100% when the machine doesn't have anything else to do so isn't a problem.

Comment: Hi @HansPassant, thanks for your reply. Do you mean to say that it wouldn't be possible to debug the source code at my end? What minimum I want, is to see which line of code in a window service application is taking more time. Most of what you have suggested is not easily understandable at my level :)